# How to disable generating GpuCapability.log on startup?

Tags: wpf, scichart

I am launching my application from different directories and in each directory **SciChart** generates a new **GpuCapability.log** file.

Is there any possibility how to disable this functionality?

I didn't find any solution how to do it

Comment: Snail, you can rephrase the question to be better. When you say "my application", what application are you referring to, and how does it relate to SciChart? e.g. Did you write an application, and it uses SciChart as a library? If so, say that, and link to the SciChart documentation. Second, say what you tried to do to try to answer the question. That helps answerers know where not to look and shows the effort that you put in before asking. e.g. Did you do a search? for what keywords. Did you find nothing? or you found some documentation or code, but you don't know how to invoke it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends a lot on the version of SciChart WPF you are using, but in the latest version, set this flag once before any SciChartSurface is shown to disable log output of the GpuCapabilityTester

```
// Enables or disables sending GPU test messages to debug output 
VisualXcceleratorEngine.WriteWarningsToOutput = false;
```

A GpuCapability.log file is also created when that flag is true, this shouldn't be the case so it will be logged for future improvement.

Comment: Update: in 7.0.2 GPU Caps logging is disabled by default. GPU Capability log to console or file may be explicitly enabled by setting VisualXcceleratorEngine.WriteWarningsToFile / WriteWarningsToOutput. See https://www.scichart.com/scichart-v7-0-2-update